# How to select using lat/lng radius with a SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, gis, latitude-longitude

I have a [SQL function](http://weblogs.asp.net/jimjackson/archive/2009/02/13/calculating-distances-between-latitude-and-longitude-t-sql-haversine.aspx) that calculates the distance between two points using their lat/lng coordinates. Using this function, I can shortlist a set of locations from a large set (*GEOCODES table*) based on their distance for a given point like so:

```
DECLARE @LAT1 float, @LNG1 float,
SET @LAT1 = '34.169540'
SET @LNG1 = '-92.590990'

SELECT E.* FROM GEOCODES E
WHERE dbo.fnGetDistance(E.lat, E.lng, @LAT1, @LNG1, 'miles') < '20'
```

I have a second table (*GEOMILES*) with distances between points in the form:

```
LOCATION1  | STATE1  |  LOCATION2  |  STATE2  | DISTANCE
-----------+---------+-------------+----------+---------
New York   |   NY    |    Boston   |   MA     |   220
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a `SELECT` query that returns a distance of 220 if a departure point is within 20 miles of New York, and an arrival point is within 20 miles of Boston. So far, I have this but it returns nothing when I know from checking manually that the lat/lng points etc add up. Any help is much appreciated!

```
DECLARE @FROM_LOC VARCHAR(100), @FROM_STA VARCHAR(2), @TO_LOC VARCHAR(100), @TO_STA VARCHAR(2)

SET @FROM_LOC = 'NEWARK'
SET @FROM_STA = 'NJ'

SET @TO_LOC = 'MEDFORD'
SET @TO_STA = 'MA'      

SELECT G.DIST FROM GEOMILES G, GEOCODES E
JOIN GEOCODES C ON C.asciiname = @FROM_LOC AND C.admin1 = @FROM_STA
JOIN GEOCODES D ON D.asciiname = @TO_LOC AND D.admin1 = @TO_STA
WHERE dbo.fnGetDistance(E.lat, E.lng, C.lat, C.lng, 'miles') < '20'
AND dbo.fnGetDistance(E.lat, E.lng, D.lat, D.lng, 'miles') < '20'
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  If so, could you make use of the GEOGRAPHY data type, or are you unable to alter the table definition?  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/18/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-geography-data-type-calculating-distance-between-two-points-on-the-earth-day-18-of-35/

Comment: I am using SQL server and I can alter the table. Do you know if using the STDistance() method improves the performance by any chance?

Comment: Not sure as I haven't seen the code for your function - have a play and compare.  The reason I suggest it is generally it's best to use existing functionality over rolling your own as it's been coded, tested and optimised for you, other sql folk are already familiar with it, and it'll upgrade with your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after (using you table structure). . .

```
SELECT G.DIST
FROM GEOMILES G
, GEOCODES F --from airport
, GEOCODES E --to airport
, GEOCODES C --from location
, GEOCODES D --to location

WHERE C.asciiname = @FROM_LOC 
AND C.admin1 = @FROM_STA

AND D.asciiname = @TO_LOC 
AND D.admin1 = @TO_STA

AND dbo.fnGetDistance(F.lat, F.lng, C.lat, C.lng, 'miles') < 20
AND dbo.fnGetDistance(E.lat, E.lng, D.lat, D.lng, 'miles') < 20

and G.Location1 = F.asciiname
and G.Location2 = E.asciiname
and G.State1 = F.admin1
and G.State2 = E.admin1
```

Alternate version (I think this will perform better)

```
SELECT G.DIST
FROM GEOMILES G
inner join
(
    select fromAirport.asciiname
    , fromAirport.admin1
    from GeoCodes fromAirport
    where exists
    (
        select top 1 1
        from GeoCodes fromLocation
        where fromLocation.asciiname = @FROM_LOC
        and fromLocation.admin1 = @FROM_STA
        and dbo.fnGetDistance(fromLocation.lat, fromLocation.lng, fromAirport.lat, fromAirport.lng, 'miles') < 20
    )
) fromA
    on G.Location1 = fromA.asciiname
    and G.State1 = fromA.admin1
inner join
(
    select toAirport.asciiname
    , toAirport.admin1
    from GeoCodes toAirport
    where exists
    (
        select top 1 1
        from GeoCodes toLocation
        where toLocation.asciiname = @TO_LOC
        and toLocation.admin1 = @TO_STA
        and dbo.fnGetDistance(toLocation.lat, toLocation.lng, toAirport.lat, toAirport.lng, 'miles') < 20
    )
) toA
    on G.Location1 = toA.asciiname
    and G.State1 = toA.admin1
```

Comment: yes, this one worked, thanks. I'm playing around with the native GEOGRAPHY type as well because I'm taking a big performance hit. btw, the function is at the link on the first line of the question.

Comment: alt version works much better, went from 5 secs to 1. Thanks again.

Comment: Looks nice (and is more thorough than I had time for), but without an `ORDER BY` to go with that `TOP`, your results are undefined.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks mate.  In this case an order by shouldn't be required - I'm just checking that at least 1 match exists.  When there's at least 1 match it will return a single row with a 1, otherwise nothing's returned.  I suspect SQL probably optimises in the background anyway, so my top 1 may not be required, but it does no harm / may help performance on some dbs.

Comment: @John - just remembered that I have an added complexity which is that FROM_LOC and TO_LOC are interchangeable in the context of returning the distance from GEOMILES. Can I even fit that in?

Comment: Try where toLocation.asciiname in (@TO_LOC, @FROM_LOC) and toLocation.admin1 in (@TO_STA, @FROM_SSTA).  Do the same for fromLocation.  Then add a where clause to say toLocation.ID <> fromLocation.ID (or something along those lines to check that the to and from aren't the same; though that may not be possible/needed anyway depending on what the data in the table looks like).

Comment: #headdesk# gah, misread something again (didn't check use of `WHERE` clause?).  Although yeah, `EXISTS()` probably early-exits, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `WHERE` clause, you seem to be looking for all codes within 20 miles of both the start **AND** end locations - which you've already specified as being 220 miles apart.

Also, you're mixing explicit `JOIN`s with implicit ones (comma-separated `FROM` clause).  Please explicitly qualify all joins; among other things, how are `G` and `E` supposed to relate to each other?

Comment: `C.lat C.lng` picks up the coords for the start location, `D.lat D.lng` for the end location. `G` and `E` are not relating but each `fnGetDistance` call has to look up in `GEOCODES` so that's why I added `E` implicitly. Is that what's causing the trouble?

Comment: Well, it was the fact that you were using `E` both times in the function, look at @JohnLBevan's answer, and compare how `fnGetDistance()` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a solution - I've gone with GEOGRAPHY here to save scripting the tables, but hopefully you can easily tweak this to your needs - if not please let me know & I'll adapt:

```
--setup
    declare @OneMileInMeters int = 1609

    declare @t table
    (
        id bigint not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered
        , name nvarchar(64)
        , lat float
        , long float
        , geo geography null
    )

    insert @t
          select 'Seattle', 47.455, -122.2310, null
    union select 'Boston',  42.372,  -71.0298, null
    union select 'Chicago', 41.953,  -87.6430, null
    union select 'Spokane', 47.668, -117.5290, null
    union select 'Philly',  39.888,  -75.2510, null
    union select 'NY',      40.7142, -74.0064, null
    union select 'Newark',  40.7356, -74.1728, null
    union select 'Medford', 42.4183, -71.1067, null

    update @t
    set geo = geography::Point(lat, long, 4326)

--query
    declare @fromLoc nvarchar(64) = 'Newark'
    , @toLoc nvarchar(64) = 'Medford'
    , @maxDistanceToAirport int = 20 * @OneMileInMeters


    select f2.name AirportFrom, t2.name AirportTo, f2.geo.STDistance(t2.geo) / @OneMileInMeters FlightDistance
    from @t f
    , @t t
    , @t f2
    , @t t2
    where f.name = @fromLoc
    and t.name = @toLoc
    and f.geo.STDistance(f2.geo) < @maxDistanceToAirport    
    and t.geo.STDistance(t2.geo) < @maxDistanceToAirport
    and t.id != t2.id
    and f.id != f2.id
```